# Show that the inverse of a projection matrix, when exists, is again a projection matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

A proof in linear algebra. Show that the inverse of a projection matrix, when exists, is again a projection matrix.

My thinking:

The definition of a projection matrix is $PP=P$. So, 
$$
PP=\frac{1}{(v\cdot v)^2}vv^{-1}vv^{-1}=\frac{1}{(v\cdot v)^2}v(v^{-1}v)v^{-1}
$$ this is what I have tried so far, not sure how to proceed or if what I have so far is correct.

Comment: This fact might be helpful: there's only one invertible projection matrix for any given $n$ ($n$ being the dimension of $\Bbb R^n$).

Comment: how do I use that in solution?

Comment: If you can figure out which matrix that is, it's obvious that its inverse is again a projection matrix.

Comment: You’re only looking at the case of orthogonal projection onto a one-dimensional subspace (i.e., projection onto a vector $v$). For a complete proof, you’ll have to consider a more general projection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $P=P^2$, if $(P)^{-1}$ exists, then $(P^2)^{-1}$ exists, so $(P^{-1})=(P^2)^{-1}=(P^{-1})^2$. In fact, it can be shown that $P=I$ is the only invertible projection matrix, so the result is obvious from this fact.

Comment: and this is the complete proof?

Comment: I just made an edit. You could go with what I originally put up (first sentence), or if you want to you could show the result I just added (i.e. in this case $P=I$), and that would suffice as a proof.

Comment: thanks so much I will consider both

Comment: If you want to show that $P=I$ use what I just showed (i.e. $P^{-1}=(P^{-1})^2$) and it should follow easily.

Answer (score 1):

(In connection with the last sentence of @Dave)

If $P$ is invertible, it is a bijective, thus $Im(P)=\mathbb{R}^n$.

What does it mean? That the space on which one projects is $\mathbb{R}^n$ in its entirety. It is thus the identity $I_n$, which is its own inverse, thus is a projection matrix...

In other words (it is why this exercise is very special), the set of matrices that are concerned is reduced to $\{I_n\}$...